# Ubuntu: DLT tool: Trace load exceeded trace hard limit. 1 messages discarded

Tags: ubuntu, logging, dlt

I am running DLT tool in Ubuntu to capture the logs.
Logs are redirected to DLT but it is not showing logs due to some problem.

**Error:** Trace load exceeded trace hard limit. 1 messages discarded.

DLT tool is not loading the error messages.
Does anyone know this or faced similar kind of problem ?

Below is the image of payload which is not loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got to know, this problem is related to trace load limits (soft limit and hard limit) mentioned in Payload column.

These limits should be set in configuration file **dlt-trace-load.conf** for each application which is using dlt daemon. These limits should be defined with corresponding application id.
Soft_limit: The warning limit, if more data than this is logged, a warning is written into dlt.
Hard_limit: If an application surpasses this limit, data will be discarded and a warning will be logged!